# How do you reset the Radio after no power in a 2008 Honda fit

Tags: honda

How can you reset the radio in a 2008 honda fit cant find the reset code in the glove box

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I took my daughter's car to the dealership and they reset it for me as well as gave me the codes (it was a nav unit, so had two). Didn't cost me a dime. Didn't buy the car from them, either.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6R72mm75LaM tells you how to extract the radio serial number.

THEN go to the genuine Honda website  https://radio-navicode.honda.com

Which will need the VIN number and the radio serial number to give you the code. IT'S FREE.

Answer (score 0):

You sure you looked through any booklets in the car? It'd be in one inside the front cover or front few pages.